how to use the externalForce to gain a Fext matrix in the MATLAB function block in simulink?
https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/forwarddynamics.html
I want to use this block in my simulink model to calculate the forward dynamics of a robotic arm, and it requires an input of Fext which is relative to the external force. And the guide told me to use the externalForce function in MATLAB function block to get the Fext.
I have tried to use the externalForce function in MATLAB function block, however, the MATLAB function block does not support the class of "rigidBodyTree" which is the input of externalForce function. I failed to load the "rigidBodyTree" from workspace nor from .mat file, and also failed to creat a new one inside the block. And because I need to use some simlink block output to calculate the external force, I can not calculate it outside the simulink.

I found an alternative  method: use the vector to calculate the external force with respect to the base frame and compose them as a matrix directly. It seems to work because the function without position input will not change my input force and just combine them together, though I am not shure whether it does simply combine the external force relative to base.
